# How do I render two different html pages passing different results

Tags: node.js, render

I make a POST call which launch a mysql query.
The results has 2 values, the first must be rendered to the 'account' page, the second to the 'layout' page. I can't merge the two renders in order to send both values to the appropriate page. (can be the same with 2 generic variables instead of query results, the idea is the same). Any suggestions?

here are the 2 renders to be merged.

res.render('account', {TodayTotal: result[0]});

res.render('layout', {Username:result[1]});

Comment: Use session or database

Comment: ok, but i can't believe there's no some js syntax issue allowing this operation. (I haven't found it at least!)

Comment: What template engine do you use?

Comment: i use express.js

Comment: express.js isn't a template engine. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i use PUG as template engine